# Migrating wordpress local to live, image links point to localhost - cannot rectify

Tags: wordpress, image, local, live, database-migration

I'd like some technical support on the issue of migrating my wordpress local site live. I'm running into some difficulties updating image links which point to localhost directories - which are invalid while the site is live. So far I have not remedied this, and have tried manually changing links in the sql database to search n replace plugins.

If I update all instances of my 'localhost/mywebsitename' in my database (again tried manual, with queries, and with plugins) - My wordpress site has css styling break (styling that points to a custom file under a child theme which I used to modify the site).

Another thing I've tried is inspecting the broken images, searched them in my database; then replaced the 'localhost' link with 'mywebsitename' link - but this does not work and displays text instead.

I've also tried 're-attaching' the unattached images one by one, and see no difference.

The site runs perfectly fine on my machine, as I developed it locally and if the links point to local directories the files are still there.

Could someone perhaps shed some light on the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things to check as well as doing the usual search and replace functions.

First, check you're `htaccess` is correct. You're localhost copy may have some redirect problems or url problems in the file so just double check it and possibly replace it. The basic WP `htaccess` can be found on the website. [WP HTAccess](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Next you'll want to check your WP Settings within the admin panel.

First, go into settings -> general and double check that WordPress address and Site address are correct.

Secondly, go into settings -> permalinks and check that the link structure is okay.

If this still doesn't work, try doing a whole new clean install of wordpress and then using the backup and import method within the wordpress tools.

More information on everything can be found [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)